# changing the number of decimal places in `skimr` output for numeric variables

Tags: r, summary, skimr

I am using `skimr::skim_to_wide` function to look at the summary of my data. But I can't seem to figure out how to change the number of decimal places in the summary output for numeric variables.

For example, here the mean is always `"3.22"`, but I'd like to get a more precise value like `"3.21725"`. Note that I am using `options(pillar.sigfig = 6)` because `skimr` always returns a `tibble`.

```r
options(digits = 6)
mean(mtcars$wt)

#> [1] 3.21725

options(pillar.sigfig = 6)
skimr::skim_to_wide(mtcars$wt)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 13
#>   type  variable missing complete n     mean  sd    p0    p25   p50   p75  
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 nume~ x        0       32       32    3.22  0.98  1.51  2.58  3.33  3.61 
#> # ... with 2 more variables: p100 <chr>, hist <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does mention in the [package docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skimr/skimr.pdf) that you can format the digits e.g. see `skim_format` function and `skim_format(numeric=list(digits=4))`. If you run this prior to `skimr::skim_to_wide(mtcars$wt)` it is now 4 digits

Was quite difficult to find!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `skimr 2.0`, btw. This new release should be on CRAN in the next few days.

Comment: This is discussed [here](https://github.com/ropensci/skimr/issues/531), He haven't specified how to pass them as arugments though.